# How to store uknown number of job fields

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this job offering system - each offer can be posted for unknown number of work categories (Finance, IT, Services, ...) and can be posted for unknown number of regions (Europe, Asia, America,...). First thing that came into my mind was to create an extra table that would just store `region_id, category_id, offer_id` but that seems a bit redundant isnt it? So a second thought was to serialize data e.g. as JSON and then store it in DB - but I also want to retrieve those data and join them on table that goes like `region_id region_name` and `category_id category_name` and that seems to be performance-hard to do  when it would be stored as JSON isnt it?

So how do I store these uknown number of ids? Can it be effectively done without relations?

Thanks

**PS:** I am using PHP&MySQL

Comment: Why the downvotes? Please at least submit a solid comment when downvoting a question, thanks.

Comment: why not two tables, offer_categories and offer_regions? unless an offer is like offered in Europe only for Finance and then in Asia for Finance and IT? then one table like you suggested should be fine.

Comment: @TinTran Well it is an unless - one offer can be for France; IT,Management,  otherone France;Management , third one Asia,Europe;Finance , ... ? So what then? BTW: Do you know what are the "downvoters" mad about?

Comment: what i mean is if an offer is for France;IT,Management and the same offer is for Asia;Finance then you can use your one table because each category depends on region for the same offer, but if they're different offers and if it's an just France;IT,Management then you can have one row for offer_regions(offer_id,region_id) and two rows for offer_categories(offer_id,category_id). And No I don't know why your question is downvoted. I didn't downvote it :)

Comment: @TinTran these are two different offers :) So relation then huh?

Comment: yeah like 2 tables you mean? yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create 2 tables

- offer_categories(offer_id,category_id)
- offer_regions(offer_id,region_id)

here's a sample of 2 offers that you've described in your commenting ([sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f86f4/9/0))